# Can you upload a file in Cypress?

Tags: html, typescript, cypress

I have a Cypress test in which I would like to upload a specific file - can this be done?

Here is my html code - there's not much to it...

```
<form class="FileUploadForm" [formGroup]="projectionForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="files" class="btn onFileUploadButton">Select Import file: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="files" name='' type="file" (change)="onFileUpload($event)" class="onFileUploadInput"
        formControlName="importFile" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to implement a Cypress test to upload a specific file?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps as I see them:

**Attach the file**

You have an input of `type="file"` that needs a file attached.

You can probably use [selectFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile). Where is the file you want to handle? Most likely in the fixture folder

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile('@myFixture')
```

or could be a non-fixture file

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile('path/to/file.json')
```

**Trigger the upload**

You have a change event handler on the input, maybe you need to trigger that change event.

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]')
  .selectFile('path/to/file.json')
  .trigger('change')
```

**Verify the upload**

You need to see that the file has gone somewhere. Since it's an upload, it would be on the server. Does your API allow you to check the server?

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]')
  .selectFile('path/to/file.json')
  .trigger('change')

cy.request('upload-url/file.json')
  .should('have.status', 200)
```

If not, leave the server out of the equation by adding a stubbing intercept

```js
cy.intercept('upload-url/file.json', {//stub to throw away the request})
  .as('upload')

cy.get('input[type=file]')
  .selectFile('path/to/file.json')
  .trigger('change')

cy.wait('@upload').then(({request}) => {
  expect(request.body)...                // some assertion on the file attachment
})
```